# Overwrite input file using awk

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

I have the following line of code:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%09d,%d\n" ,$1,$2}' $newDir/$processNew
```

and it does what I want it to, but instead of overwriting the current file, it prints out of screen.

What do I need to change to overwrite the current input file which is $processNew ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the source file, you need to use a temporary file file:

```
awk -F, '{printf "%09d,%d\n" ,$1,$2}' $newDir/$processNew > tmp && mv tmp $newDir/$processNew
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk, you can do

```
gawk -i inplace -options 'script' file ...
```

or

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak -options 'script' file ...
```

ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html

Comment: I'm curious; how does one make those extensions work? It's obviously not part of posix awk. My awk (GNU Awk 4.0.1) on ubuntu 14.04 knows nothing of a -i switch.

Comment: Don't know what version added them. Possibly 4.3. So upgrade to make them work

Comment: 4.1.3 ... ? anyway, got 4.1.1 from PPA, and that has it.   What had me confused was the -i ... I didn't expect that to load that extension, but to work analogously to the one in sed. :)