# Shell Scripting, 'sed' usage, String substitution in a file

Tags: bash, shell, sed, scripting

I know this question has probably been answered before. I have seen many threads about this in various places, but the answers are not working for me. I am looking for help with an example usage of the 'sed' command.

What I am trying to do is reading some strings from a file and then using those values to replace the strings of few other files

Example:

```
File1.txt

name:
abcd

age:
22

File2.xml

<root>
 <name>xxxx</name>
 <age>xxxx</age>
</root>
```

I am reading name and age from file 1 and trying to replace missing values in the file 2.
I have tried to use hard coding and replacing the values in a file :

```
$name=abcd
$age=22

sed -e 's/.*<name>\([^<]*\)</name>.*/${name}/g' file2.xml
```

*Note: it is not possible to use sed -i. Old version I guess*

for the above script I am getting an error

```
sed: 0602-404 Function s/.*<name>\([^<]*\)</name>.*/${name}/g cannot be parsed.
```

so first of all I'd like a **script to read from the file** and then a **script to write in to a file** without creating a new file.

UPDATE :

for the below added $ mark

```
$ sed -e 's/.*<name>\([^<]*\)</name>.*/${name}/g' file2.xml
```

I am getting error`./test.sh: line 4: $: command not found`

Comment: Which sed are you using? Show output of `sed --version`. What does `sed --help` say for using `-i`?Please quote the relevant part of --help. What other influence does the age of your servers have on seds handling of `-i`?

Comment: @Yunnosch i am using an GNU Bash, version 4.2.50. I am unable to get an output for `sed --version` or `sed --help`

Comment: How are you executing the sed scripts you are working on or asking about?

Comment: I am saving it as myScript.sh file and then execute in bash as ./myScript.sh. hope that makes sense

Comment: Please type into your bash commandline `sed --version`. What is the output? Otherwise replace inside your script the existing sed line with `sed --version`, then execute the script and show the output.

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried both that. No Luck :(
this is a line in another script file which I did not write
`appGroup=$(cat $ConfigFile | grep appGroup | grep -v 'appGroups'| grep -v '<!'| sed -e 's,.*<appGroup>\([^<]*\)</appGroup>.*,\1,g')
`
this works fine

Comment: Give more details on "No Luck". What happened or in which way did it fail? Did anything happen, even if not what we want?

Comment: for both methods, 
`sed: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
        sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]`

Comment: Are we talking AIX? In that case check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Answer (score 1):

First, you need `""` instead of `''` to fetch the `value` of a variable.
And, you should use `capture group` instead.

```
$ sed -r -e "s|(.*<name>)[^<]+(</name>)|\1${name}\2|g" -e "s|(.*<age>)[^<]+(</age>)|\1${age}\2|g" File2.txt
<root>
 <name>abcd</name>
 <age>22</age>
</root>
```

Or just put `${name}` outside of the `''`:

```
$ sed -r -e 's|(.*<name>)[^<]+(</name>)|\1'${name}'\2|g' -e 's|(.*<age>)[^<]+(</age>)|\1'${age}'\2|g' File2.txt
<root>
 <name>abcd</name>
 <age>22</age>
</root>
```

PS: maybe can don't have the `write permission` for File2.txt, so you can NOT use `-i.bak`

Comment: I think I have the write permissions since I created both files.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use `awk`, it's a more straightforward method.

Use the command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
  if(match($0,/name/)){getline;name=$0}
  if(match($0,/age/)){getline;age=$0}
  next}
  /<name>/{gsub(/>.*</,">"name"<",$0)}
  /<age>/{gsub(/>.*</,">"age"<",$0)}
  {print}
' File1.txt File2.xml
```

Output:

```
<root>
 <name>abcd</name>
 <age>22</age>
</root>
```

Brief explanation:

1. `match()`: extract the name & age from `File1.txt`
2. `gsub()`: to substitute name & age in File2.xml

Comment: Thanks I will try it. :)

Comment: How can I run awk in Bash ? Same as shell scripting. like ./myScript.sh ? would work for awk too?

Comment: Hi, no more file would be added in this way. @Hasith, just paste the command to your bash environment should be okay.

Comment: I added the code in to a shellscript and executed it to see it print the output as i wanted to see, but it doesn't change the config.xml as I wanted.

Comment: @Hasith, `awk` did not modify the original file actually. But you may follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795186/overwrite-input-file-using-awk to overwrite the file, a tmp file is required.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that, I am afraid that it might not work for me since, I need to edit only specific tags in the xml file. If I used a temp file I would have to create the whole config file in the script. And I can't change two different xml files which have the same tags that I want to change and have more tags unique to that file.