# Replace the second entry in all lines containing a specific string in bash

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I would like to replace the second entry of all (space or tab-separated) lines containing a specific string. In the following text

```
1078.732700000 0.00001000 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED 

-1077.336700000 0.00001000 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
```

I would like to replace `0.00001000` by `0.00005214` (searching for the string `81SaWoLa`). The result should be

```
1078.732700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED 

-1077.336700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
```

Could you please help me how to perform it?

Comment: `perl -a -F'\s+' -lne '$F[1]='0.00005214'if/1SaWoLa/;print "@F"' file` | add `-i` if you need **edit in place**

Answer (score 2):

Try this for `GNU sed`:

```
$ cat input.txt 
1078.732700000 0.00001000 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED 

-1077.336700000 0.00001000 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
$ sed -r '/81SaWoLa/s/^([^ \t]+[ \t]+)[^ \t]+(.*)/\10.00005214\2/' input.txt 
1078.732700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED 

-1077.336700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
```

Comment: you can paste the input and the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `awk` to achieve your goal more easily.

```
$ awk '/81SaWoLa/{$2="0.00005214"}1' file
1078.732700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED

-1077.336700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
```

With the variables to be used, used the command as followed,

```
$ var1=81SaWoLa
$ var2=0.00005214
$ awk -v var1=$var1 -v var2=$var2 '$0 ~ var1{$2=var2}1' file
1078.732700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 39 13 27 0 0 0 40 14 26 81SaWoLa.43 BAD LABEL, REASSIGNED

-1077.336700000 0.00005214 1 0 0 45 12 34 0 0 0 46 13 34 81SaWoLa.48 BAD LABEL
```

Comment: How to perform it if 81SaWoLa and 0.00005214 are variables? I tried awk "/$var1/ { $2 = $var2 }; 1" input.txt, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Could I execute it in place (with var1 and var2)?

Comment: @Roloka, you may use the modified answer to do that.

Comment: It seems to you tried to execute the result of `awk` directly, it's not possible. Show me your command cause the failure.

Comment: Sorry, I recognized that the "input.txt" had been executed... Thus, there is no problem. Is it possible to use awk "in place"?

Comment: I mean that the replacement "0.00001000->0.00005214" happens in the input file.

Comment: You may follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795186/overwrite-input-file-using-awk to overwrite the file using `awk`, a tmp file is required.  Use this: `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`

Comment: `awk '/'${var1}'/{$2="'${var2}'"}1' input.txt >output.txt` maybe work. but not really inplace ...

Comment: `awk '/'${var1}'/{$2="'${var2}'"}1' input.txt |tee input.txt` can work for both requirements, but fails sometimes. sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Use awk:

```
$ awk '/pattern/ { $2 = "new string." }; 1' input.txt
```

In your case:

```
$ awk '/81SaWoLa/ { $2 = "0.00005214" }; 1' input.txt
#      ^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
#      For lines    Replace second       Print each line, same as:
#      matching     column with          ``{ print $0 }''. ``$0''
#      81SaWoLa     ``0.00005214''       contains the whole line.
```

Use `-v name=val` to specify a variable:

```
$ awk -v pat="81SaWoLa"   \
      -v rep="0.00005214" \
      '$0 ~ pat { $2 = rep }; 1' input.txt
```

Comment: How to perform it if `81SaWoLa` and `0.00005214` are variables? I tried

`awk "/$var1/ { $2 = $var2 }; 1" input.txt`, but it doesn't work.