# How to use sed or awk command to set a variable based on the values of two other variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a bash script which will look for outdated entries in the conf file and update them with the new value.

The old conf file will have two entries(-CAR and -BIKE). For example,

```
#Following are the entries in the conf file
#-CAR yes/no default set to no
#-BIKE yes/no default set to no    

-CAR yes
-BIKE no
```

Now this bash script should grep for those entries and replace them with a single entry as -DRIVING_LEVEL (car/bike/none).

The logic is as follows:
If -CAR is set to yes, then DRIVING_LEVEL will be "car".
If -CAR is set to no and -BIKE is set to yes, then DRIVING_LEVEL will be "bike".
If both -CAR and -BIKE are set to none, then DRIVING_LEVEL will be "none".

I have written the following script which does the exact thing.

```
#!/bin/bash
CONF_FILE="license.conf"

grep -w $CONF_FILE -e '-CAR' -e '-BIKE'  > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Old values are present"
        var=$(grep -w $CONF_FILE -e '-CAR')
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                temp="${var##*$'\n'}"
                option=$(echo $temp | sed 's/.* //g')
                echo $option
                if [ "$option" == "yes" ]; then
                        car=1
                elif [ "$option" == "no" ]; then
                        car=0
                fi
                echo "Deleting $var"
                sed -i '/-CAR/d' $CONF_FILE
        fi

        var2=$(grep -w $CONF_FILE -e '-BIKE')
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                temp2="${var2##*$'\n'}"
                option=$(echo $temp2 | sed 's/.* //g')
                echo $option
                if [ "$option" == "yes" ]; then
                        bike=1
                        #echo $temp
                elif [ "$option" == "no" ]; then
                        bike=0
                fi
                echo "Deleting $var2"
                sed -i '/-BIKE/d' $CONF_FILE
        fi

        if [ "$car" == "1" ]; then
                driving_level="car"
        elif [ "$bike" == "1" ]; then
                driving_level="bike"
        else
                driving_level="none"
        fi

echo "Appending -DRIVING_LEVEL $driving_level"
echo "-DRIVING_LEVEL $driving_level" >> $CONF_FILE
else
        echo "No old values"
fi
```

The things is that I think this is too long and can be shortened using sed or awk commands. But I couldn't make it. I want it to be as short as possible.

Thanks in advance !

Note:

- I have used **temp="${var##*$'\n'}"** to retrieve the last line which has the actual value because grep will give both the lines containing -BIKE.
- I have used **option=$(echo $temp | sed 's/.* //g')** because there can be any number of spaces between -BIKE and yes/no.

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts here, could you please also show the expected output out of this logics and sample Input_file, kindly share that too into your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for the reply. The input file will be similar to what I have mentioned in the question. The output should be that the conf file should contain only -DRIVING_LEVEL entry which will be set to either car, bike or none. Hope that answers your question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '($0 ~ /-CAR.*yes$/){dl="car";exit} ($0 ~ /-BIKE.*yes$/){dl="bike"} END{print "-DRIVING_LEVEL",(dl)?dl:"none"}' license.conf
-DRIVING_LEVEL car
```

Brief explanation,

- `$0 ~ /-CAR.*yes$/`: if "-CAR yes" is found, print the result directly (that's the reason I use `exit` here)
- `($0 ~ /-BIKE.*yes$/)`: if "-BIKE yes" is found, keep finding the follow up lines since there's possibility to find "CAR".
- Print the result as "none" if nothing is found.

Comment: I have one more doubt. I want to delete the old entries of -BIKE and -CAR. Right now I'm doing it by using the sed command twice.

sed -i '/-BIKE/d' license.conf
sed -i '/-CAR/d' license.conf

Is there any better and cleaner way to do it ?

Comment: `awk` is not the tool to modify the file, unless you can accept the method in this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795186/overwrite-input-file-using-awk, then I can give you the `awk` solution

Comment: I found it myself. 

sed -i '/-CAR\|-BIKE/d' license.conf

Answer (score 0):

Your whole script can just be:

```
awk '1; /^-CAR/ && $2 == "yes" {DL="car"} /^-BIKE/ && $2 == "yes" {DL="bike"}
  END{print "-DRIVING_LEVEL", DL}' DL=none license.conf
```

This just appends a value for DRIVING_LEVEL at the end (note that if both car and bike are "yes", this will select the last one in the file, but you didn't specify what behavior you want in that case.)  If you want to suppress the output of the original values:

```
awk '/^-CAR/ && $2 == "yes" {DL="car"} /^-BIKE/ && $2 == "yes" {DL="bike"}
  ! (/^-CAR/ || /^-BIKE/)
  END{print "-DRIVING_LEVEL", DL}' DL=none license.conf
```

To check for the existence of the original entries, you can do:

```
awk '/^-CAR/{DL=($2 == "yes" ? "car" : "none"); next} 
     /^-BIKE/{ if(DL== "unset" || DL == "none"){DL=($2 == "yes" ?"bike":"none")} next}
  1
  END{
    if(DL=="unset") { print "missing values" > "/dev/stderr"; exit 1 }
      else
    print "-DRIVING_LEVEL", DL}' DL=unset license.conf
```

Although if entries are missing this will output the file before finally noticing and emitting the error message.  Probably cleaner to pre-check the input.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I also want to delete the old entries of  -BIKE and -CAR. And most importantly, this needs to be done only when there are old entries. It shouldn't be appending the new entry as "DRIVING_LEVEL none"  every time !

Comment: I meant that if -CAR is set to yes, irrespective of -BIKE the -DRIVING_LEVEL should be "car".